# Registering as individual for iOS development still requires company name

Tags: ios, developer-program

I actually have 3 questions, but the one in the title is the main one.

1. As I was trying to register, I have entered my apple ID and that takes me to a page where I can edit my contact info. I can change everything, except my name, which I would need to change, since somehow there is a wrong name there. (It is actually an old name which I have changed and if I go to "manage my apple ID" page I can see the new name, just the developer site still has the old one). Since they will probably be checking that against information on my credit card this could be a problem.
2. Even though I am registering as an individual, there is still a field for company name and it has to be filled. What do I put there?
3. This would probably be more of a question for apple directly, but in case someone knows, can I use a pseudonym to be shown as the "app seller", because I would rather have that than my full name there.

I tried to contact apple about these issues, but it seems that you need to be registered there to receive any support.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store, and Apple Developer Programs are off topic for Ask Different. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Even though I am registering as an individual, there is still a field for company name and it has to be filled. What do I put there?

Put your name again.

Answer (score 1):

To have a company name as seller name in all places in the App store, you need to enroll as a company.  In order to enroll as a company, you will need to have valid state incorporation papers under the company name.

Comment: Yeah, that I understand, but since I don't have a company I'm enrolling as an individual and just don't like having my name all over the place. It's not a big deal really, just thought if it's possible...